# How to remove class symbol from package explorer?

Tags: eclipse

Can someone tell me how to remove those class symbols, green circles from package explorer? Im using eclipse and couldn't find a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Package Explorer to show the contents of .java files open the Preferences and go to 'Java > Appearance'. Deselect the 'show members in Package Explorer' option.